# How can i get this value? DJANGO

Tags: django, database

I would like to collect this value and pass it by post to the database
I want to pass `{{qs.nombre}}` and `{{ user.user }}` but i try this and not run..

When i try `request.POST['maquina']`:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liWpe.png)

My code here:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for qs in queryset %}
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12">
            <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                <legend class="scheduler-border">EMPLEADO</legend>
                <b><p class="black">Identificado: </b>{{ user.username }}</p>
                <b><p class="black">Empleado: </b>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }} </p>
                <b><p class="black">IP: </b>{{ qs.ip }}</p>
                <b><p class="black">Maquina: </b><input type="text" name="maquina" value="{{ qs.nombre }}" disabled /></p>
                <b><p class="black">Nº Maq: </b><input type="text" name="rec_" value="{{ qs.rec }}" disabled/></p>
                <b><p class="black">Usuario: </b><input type="text" name="user" value="{{ user.user}}" disabled/></p>
           </fieldset>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def show_trabajos(request):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    maquina = 189
    codusuari = '161'
    qs = info_equipos.objects.all().filter(ip=ip_add)
    sentencia = "exec [Empresa].[dbo].[PT_GET_ORDENES]" + str(maquina) + "," + codusuari
    cursor.execute(sentencia)

    results = namedtuplefetchall(cursor)

    if request.method == "POST":
        maquina = request.POST.get('maquina')
        user = request.POST.get('user')
        ins = info(maquina=maquina, user=user)
        ins.save()
        return redirect('trabajo_final')

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'results': results
    }
```

Comment: try request.POST.get('maquina')

Comment: the null value for the "machine" column violates the not null constraint
DETAIL:

Comment: please add your `views.py`

Comment: Edited, you can see my views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all your `<input>` fields have attribute `disabled`, and as such they are not submitted. Try printing `request.POST` in your view, you'll see the data are missing there. What you want to do instead is to use `readonly` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="maquina" value="{{ qs.nombre }}" readonly />
```